# Привязка к StackPanel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Как к StackPanel привязать ObservalCollection? Вот так я понимаю нельзя:

```
<StackPanel Children="{Binding collection}">
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Прямо к `StackPanel` привязаться нельзя, у неё нет понятия «источника внутренних элементов». Но для таких целей есть `ItemsControl` (или производные от него):

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding collection}"
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```